# Is there a non-SEDE or userscript way to find one's most upvoted comment?

Tags: support, comments, search

To find one's most upvoted comment, a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/415462/get-all-comments-for-a-specified-user-in-a-descending-order-by-score) can be used.

Is there a way to do that from the Stack Overflow UI?

Comment: No. comments aren't searchable and there's no list of them that includes "score"

Comment: There's no other way to do that except userscripts and SEDE queries ...

Comment: Though, i guess that depends on your idea of "easy". You could click through each comment, keeping note of the highest scoring one you find as you go... experience gets worse as your account age/activity climbs.

Comment: Related post on MSE: [How to search score of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256232/how-to-search-score-of-comments)

Comment: With 54 comments, you can just look through each. It's probably easier than a SEDE query. But doesn't really scale well. I would not recommend it if you have, for example, 18533 comments.